# JS Loading External Script and Configuring Locally

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say someone would like to insert the following into their site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://foo.com/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Plugin.Setup({userId: 100});

</script>
```

In this situation plugin.js creates a "Plugin" object which has a "Setup" method.

The problem is that the following error will be thrown:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Plugin is not defined
```

Which is understandable since you can't call a method of an undefined object.

This approach would fix the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://foo.com/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initiatePlugin() {
        Plugin.Setup({userId: 100});
    }

    window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener('load', initiatePlugin) : window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent('onload', initiatePlugin);
</script>
```

However, I see other plugins get away with this kind of thing. For example TypeKit has the following embed code:

```
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/sgye3663.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
```

What they're relying on is that the external script `https://use.typekit.net/sgye3663.js` loads faster than the local script calling "Typekit.load" and in the case where an error is throw, Typekit will never load.

Is this the right way to go about plugin design? Or would it be just better to wait for window onload events?

Comment: It's better to wait until the page is loaded to start executing code.  It is likely that `typekit.load()` is just an event listener, just like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to wait until the page fully loads, and then execute a method from external object